# Null Pointer Exception when program not run through debugger

Tags: java, oop, debugging, nullpointerexception

I am developing a game in Java for a school project. When I run my code by typing 'java game' into the command prompt, I get a null pointer exception (at game.play, line 35, "gameScreen.tick();"), however when I add a breakpoint on this line and use a debugger to investigate, the debugger shows the correct object reference and follows the program without any problems. I can't seem to work out what is wrong...

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class game implements Runnable {

    private screen gameScreen;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // put your code here
        game thisGame = new game();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(thisGame);
        thisGame.play();
    }

    public void run() {
        JFrame w = new JFrame();
        w.setDefaultCloseOperation(w.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gameScreen = new screen();
        gameScreen = gameScreen.setUp();
        w.add(gameScreen);
        w.pack();
        w.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        w.setVisible(true);
    } 

    public void play() {
        while(true) {
            try { Thread.sleep(10); }
            catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }
        gameScreen.tick();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: what class is screen ? ..can you point the line here where the exception occurs.

Comment: gameScreen.tick() is unreachable. Your IDE should really tell you this...

Comment: its a class private variable why would it be unreachable ?

Comment: @tm.sauron I was unclear - I meant the method call after the try/catch. I assume it's meant to be in the while loop.

Answer (score 3):

`invokeLater()` is an asynchronous call and will be invoked later as the name suggests.

Your next line calls `thisGame.play()` which in turn calls `gameScreen.tick()` after 10ms which may be uninitialized at the time.

The reason that the debugger works, is that the wait is probably long enough between method calls to allow `gameScreen` to be initialized by the `run()` method

Comment: That's very likely it. OP is looking at a classical race condition, which is resolved by the Debugger blocking the offending Thread. Alternatively to initializing in the constructor, the initial tick can be executed by the run method.

Answer (score 3):

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) gives below example for SwingUtilities.invokeLater method.

```
Runnable doHelloWorld = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello World on " + Thread.currentThread());
    }
};

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doHelloWorld);
System.out.println("This might well be displayed before the other message.");
```

You can see `This might well be displayed before the other message.` might print before `Hello World on`.

So in your case `gameScreen = new screen();` might not be executed before `gameScreen.tick();`, so you are getting NPE.

**Solution:** 
You can initialize gameScreen in the `default constructor` of game class.